# Storing of values in from one array to other arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I had two arrays named a and b which i should store in other arrays p,q,r and .Such that p array and q array should poses values of a array and b array respectively from `a[0]` to `a[n-1]` and `b[0]` to `b[n-1]` ( here n is last index of a ).Coming to r and s arrays they should posses values of `a[1]` to `a[n]` and `b[1]` to `b[n]` respectively. I had written code using for loop it works for me though i got an error  named :

> Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\linearray_printarray.php on line 25

Here is the code:

```html
<?php
$a=array(100,100,200,200);
$b=array(200,300,300,200);
$total= count($a);
$tot=$total-1;
$to=$total+1;
$c=0;

for($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++)
{
    $p[]=$a[$i];
    $q[]=$b[$i];
    echo"<br>$p[$i]</br>";
    echo"<br>$q[$i]</br>";
}

for($j=0;$j<$total;$j++)
{
    if($j>"0"){
        $r[]=$a[$j];
        $s[]=$b[$j];
    }
}

for($k=0;$k<$total;$k++)
{
    echo"<br> $r[$k]</br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use array functions.
array_pop() to remove last element from array and array_shift() to remove the first element.
You can use below code.
    $p=$a;
    $q=$b;
    $r=$a;
    $s=$b;
    array_pop($p);
    array_pop($q);
    array_shift($r);
    array_shift($s);
    print_r($p);
    print_r($q);
    print_r($r);
    print_r($s);

Hope this will help you.